# Upgrading PuTTY to 0.77 from 0.63, but old version cannot be removed

Tags: windows-8, installation, putty, uninstall

I'm using a Windows 8 system that originally had PuTTY 0.63 installed.  I then uninstalled it (by running the uninstall option under Control Panel/Programs and Features) and installed 0.77.  This worked fine, until an unrelated fault meant I had to revert the system to a system restore point from before this update was made.

After the system restore operation, the old version of PuTTY returned.  I could not install 0.77, as the installer tells me that I must uninstall the old version.  However, the uninstaller does not work, telling me that `unins000.dat` is missing.

I've tried deleting the files manually, but 0.77 still will not install.  Also, I've tried looking for an entry for PuTTY in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` as recommended in the question that has been suggested is a duplicate of this one, but there isn't one.  I believe the uninstaller must have removed its registry entries when it ran, but PuTTY must have left something behind. I need to find that before I can install the new version, but what is it?

Comment: And did you check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - no, because that wasn't mentioned in the answers to the question above.  This is the correct answer here.  Thanks.

Comment: Good. I've added comment to the answer by @LPChip.